# Android Linkify

Tags: android, linkify

I am trying to create an Android Activity page, SecondaryActivity that provides a link to a webpage that opens a web browser with a specified link. I am launching the Activity page from my Main Activity page like this:

```
Intent  intent = new Intent(this, SecondaryActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

I have the following code in my SecondaryActivity but it gives the error below:

Code

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Map<String,Float> sampleData) {
             TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainTable);
             if(sampleData == null) { 
                 // If no information is found for the user, add the message to the view letting them know where
                 // to go to set up their appliances...

                 TextView tvDynamicKey = new TextView(getApplicationContext());                     
                 tvDynamicKey.setText("No appliances have been found, please help us by \nlogging onto our website. Click here.");
                 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("here");
                 String scheme = "http://www.google.com/";
                 Linkify.addLinks(tvDynamicKey, pattern, scheme);

                 tvDynamicKey.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(1));

                 TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

                 tr.setId(101);
                 tr.addView(tvDynamicKey);
                 table.addView(tr);

                 TextView tvDynamicKey2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                 tvDynamicKey2.setText("Contact me at test@test.com \nfor details!");
                 pattern = Pattern.compile("test@test.com");
                 scheme = "test@test.com";
                 Linkify.addLinks(tvDynamicKey2, pattern, scheme);

                 // TODO When I click  the link here, I get an error:

                 tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                 tr.setId(102);
                 tr.addView(tvDynamicKey2);
                 table.addView(tr);
             } 
    }
```

Error

```
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:617)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:258)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:216)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6577)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-21 23:31:52.715: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(838):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Linkify wont work if you are trying it with simulator if it map address, but it works fine for the rest. Here in your code you are trying to open a browser by providing a link and there is no problem in that, that is perfect. When i saw your error logs i can tell you that its not problem with your linkify. You are trying to call your activity from outside the context. In this case while starting the activity start it with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Hope this will resolve your problem

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I'm still getting the same error (01-22 01:05:52.926: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1428): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want) but I am now starting the activity in the following manner:                                                 Intent  intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ApplianceActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: try starting activity like this "yourclassname.this.startActivity(intent);"

Comment: I get the error "No enclosing instance of the type ApplianceActivity is accessible in scope"

Comment: I misunderstood your suggestion; I tried to start the activity in this way and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this method to work so I went with the following method per the website: http://mgmblog.com/2009/01/06/four-different-ways-of-opening-a-web-page-in-android/:

```
<TableRow>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/link1_lbl"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:paddingRight="5dip"/>
            <!--
                Using autoLink='web' to show the text as a web link
             -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/link1_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:text=""/>
        </TableRow>
```

I programmatically set the link1_lbl and link1_view attributs